# Is the word `credentials` singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

I know that the word **credentials** is the plural form of **credential**.

And I'm referring to a single pair of username and password as credentials. [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/credential) also suggests that the word **credentials** is widely used over the word **credential**. Taking all these into account,

Which of the following is right?

- The credentials that you have provided **are** invalid.
- The credentials that you have provided **is** invalid.

**EDIT**: I'm referring to a single pair of username and password as credentials, That's what has made me ask this question.

Comment: Often times one must present more than one credential to prove themselves in a situation which why the plural form is used most often.. You have stated correctly that credentials is plural. Therefore you would use "are".

Comment: But I will still be referring to a single pair of username and password isn't it?

Comment: in that specific case it could be considered that both the username and password are separate credentials as they both need to be correct to login.

Comment: The word 'credentials', though not without a singular form, is used almost as a mass noun (with obvious plural form, and taking plural agreement) like 'details'. The singular is very rare, at least in BrE. Compare 'information' which is singular in form and takes singular agreement, which has a very rare plural form, and 'data' and 'news', plural in form but treated as a singular concept and given singular agreement.

Comment: When credentials (as in a password and a username) are invalid, then this means that possibly both the password *and* username are invalid. This of course means that we are talking about 2 things, not just one -- thus, "credentials" is plural.

Comment: It may help to look at "referring to a single pair" as talking about other pairs, like shoes: I have only a single pair of shoes, and my shoes *are* black. Your trousers *are* grey. Those twins *are* not identical.

Comment: Thanks @YosefBaskin could you please add this as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Let me see. I have received criticism for accepting such invitations to post answers that are simple. Also, since we are in agreement, I don't mind if you copy the comment into your own answer and add a citation showing that shoes and credentials may come in sets and still remain plurals.

Comment: Sometimes a simple answer is the best answer. From the guidelines: *Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Merriam-Webster:
Credentials is the plural of the word credential.

It is grammatically correct to say the first option:
The credentials that you have provided are invalid.

Credentials is used over its singular form credential but it is still a plural noun.